# Calls require API level

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble with this error:

Call Requires API level 9 (current min is 7)

However, after following some solutions posted here, by adding the uses-skd part still doesn't help :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <uses-sdk
                    android:minSdkVersion="7"
                    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: change this `android:minSdkVersion="7"` to `android:minSdkVersion="9"`.the api that you use requires it to be 9

Comment: and `uses-sdk` should be declared under manifest tag. not inside `activity` tag...

Comment: For which method are you getting that error? Which android versions do you want to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the procedure, uses-sdk must be a direct child of the manifest element

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xxxxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Hi Sukan. I followed your instructions by simply changing the number 7 to 9. The error still remain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @SuppressLint("NewApi") before your method call. But do not forget to add android os version checking to avoid app crashing on older devices

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        // make your call;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means, that the user needs a specific minimum Android Version (9 is Android 2.3+). In other Words: users below 2.1 wont be able to use that feature, since the would get an Exception. So change:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" ...
```

Clean Lint or if you still want your app to be available since level 7 (Android 2.1+) and want to give that feature only to "newer" devices use an if construction:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
     // here goes the feature.
}
```

Remember that your IDE might not recognize this and still throw a Lint marker, so just surpress Lint for that Method or Class or whole Project.